# Maven HTTP Failure During Build

Tags: java, json, eclipse, maven, import

Been reading StackOverflow for a long time, and though I have seen people get this error, I am lost on how they resolved it. I am getting

> an Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false', or 'null') at [Source: <!doctype html>HTTP Status [401] [Unauthorized]h1 ... Status Report Message:  Authorization Required. The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

I am getting this particular error when I am executing the following:

```
    Json j = new JsonObject();  
    json.readTemplateString(rep.toString());
```

where it's getting the response from:

```
    HttpResponse rep = connector.httpGet(url, "", headers);
```

The Json portion of the code must be taking in an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on "where" you are making the call from, and what url you are trying to reach.  Depending on the source and destination of the connection, you may be required to provide either authentication credentials or a proxy configuration.

If you're executing this code when connected to a VPN for a company, you'll likely need to set a proxy configuration in order for the connection to work.

On the other hand, the url you're trying to connect to might require basic auth credentials.  I have no idea what you're trying to connect to, so it's hard to tell whether that's the case.

Comment: I am indeed connected to a VPN for a company, but I already have my proxy configurations set up in Eclipse, so I don't believe that is the issue. I believe I am trying to connect to a Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS server whose Cache Control is private with a max-age of 0.

Comment: The eclipse proxy config is only for connections made on behalf of eclipse, not connections from user-written code.

Comment: Oh, okay. How do I ensure this connection then?